# overflow: auto is not scrolling correctly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, safari

I have the following master-detail layout where I want the left blue column and the yellow right column to scroll. As far as I can tell, I have set a series of nested flexboxes to achieve this layout. This is working well in Safari but not is Chrome. Please see the [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-brook-der94). What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You're missing a height limitation. In order to trigger an overflow, there needs to be something to overflow. Without a fixed or max height, the element will just expand or contract based on content size, and a scrollbar will never generate because an overflow condition will never occur.

Comment: But the heights are limited. The page container is limited by `100vh` and every nested flex container is expanded to the remaining height using `flex: 1`. This technique works nicely in Safari. I am guessing there is a Chrome quirk that I am missing.

Comment: `flex: 1` is not a height. It's just a command to consume remaining space. You need to set a `flex-basis`, `height` or `max-height` somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I already had `min-height: 0` on my horizontal container, but also needed `min-height: 0` on the parent container. It has to do with automatic minimum size of flex items (see [Flexbox Specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto)). Also [this article](https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/) was very useful.

[CodeSandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-brook-der94) has been updated.